# Initialise postgres on centos docker image fails with Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted

Tags: postgresql, docker, centos

I'm trying to install postgres on a docker image, base image is running centos.

I'm following instructions at [How to Install PostgreSQL Relational Databases on CentOS 7](https://www.linode.com/docs/databases/postgresql/how-to-install-postgresql-relational-databases-on-centos-7) and here's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM our-internal-docker-registry.org/centos:7.3.1611
RUN yum install -y postgresql-server postgresql-contrib
RUN postgresql-setup initdb
```

The first RUN command succeeds however the second one fails with:

```
Step 3/3 : RUN postgresql-setup initdb
 ---> Running in d26f43467aa0
Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted
failed to find PGDATA setting in postgresql.service
The command '/bin/sh -c postgresql-setup initdb' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

I admit to being clueless as to what to do next as I'm not very familiar with postgres, or indeed linux. Hoping for some advice.

Comment: The error suggest that initdb is trying to start postgres service, so it can init the DB. But inside docker there is no systemd or init, so this won't work. You should look at the original Dockerfile of official postgres image and see what needs to be done from there

Comment: Good advice. Searching led me to here: https://github.com/sclorg/postgresql-container/blob/master/9.5/Dockerfile. Thank you @TarunLalwani

Comment: Official postgres image (https://github.com/docker-library/postgres) is base on debian whereas my org's chosen distro is centos, so I'm still a bit naive/lost.

Comment: Don't worry about that look at the `entrypoint.sh` file they use, where the would launch the server in background process first, init the db, then restart the process

Comment: Is there an organization requirement that all containers and Dockerfiles be based on CentOS? Ideally the base OS distro should be irrelevant -- i.e. nobody is running commands inside the container -- and you can just use the official `library/postgres:9.6` or `library/postgres:9.6-alpine` images. Otherwise, you're stuck translating the Debian or Alpine `docker-entrypoint.sh` scripts to work in your base `centos` image.

Comment: Thanks both for replies. Sorry its taken me a week to reply, been busy with life n stuff. Taking another look now. Watch this space.

Comment: In the end I cloned https://github.com/sclorg/postgresql-container and used that. Done.

Answer (score 4):

The "D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted" is a hint that it wants to contact the SystemD daemon. I am using postgres on centos along with https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement to avoid that.